# SUBQUERY and INNER JOIN - differences between MySQL and SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a simple query I have used its like (using LIMIT 1 rather that TOP 1) various times in my own MySQL Database:

```
SELECT
    j1.status AS "Status",
    j1.number AS "Number",
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            i2.invoicedDate
        FROM invoices AS i2
        INNER JOIN jobs AS j2 ON i2.jobKey = j2.id
        WHERE
            j1.id=j2.id
            AND
            j2.status = 'INVOICED'
    ) AS "Invoiced Date"
FROM jobs AS j1
```

Lets say there are 183,000 rows in the om.jobGroup table, in MySQL the result would return all 183,000 results - and if nothing matched within the subquery it would return NULL

When I run the same query in a Microsoft SQL server; it not only takes significantly longer but only returns like 1700 records?

What is the best way to approach this from an SQL perspective - am I barking up the wrong tree?

Removing the sub query and doing a join on the main query still results in a missmatch of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the ids are unique, I think the query you want in either database is like this:

```
SELECT j1.status AS "Status", j1.number AS "Number",
       (SELECT TOP 1 i2.invoicedDate
        FROM invoices i2
        WHERE i2.jobKey = j1.id AND j1.status = 'INVOICED'
       ) Invoiced_Date
FROM jobs j1;
```

Normally, `TOP`/`LIMIT` would be used with an `ORDER BY`.

Nothing in a subquery in the `SELECT` is going to change the number of rows.

Comment: OK, thanks for that; it looks like there is less need to do a JOIN at all within subqueries as long as the database tables are set up correctly. 

by default I have always done a join of some description... now the problem of the DB I am using is not set up correctly ;)